# Change datagriview cell value on CellValidating

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I would like to change the value of cell value which user inputs there and do the trim before to avoid left and right spaces over value before it will be validated. Currently this is my code without this feature:

```
Private Sub Grid_CellValidating(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) Handles Grid.CellValidating
Dim newValue = e.FormattedValue.ToString

If Not Grid.Rows(e.RowIndex).IsNewRow Then              'And Not e.RowIndex = Grid.NewRowIndex - 1 Then
    Select Case e.ColumnIndex
        Case 1   'Name
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(newValue) Then
                e.Cancel = True
                Exit Select
            End If
        Case Else
    End Select
End If
End Sub
```

What I tried to do was this way, but it completely doesn't work:

```
   Private Sub Grid_CellValidating(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) Handles Grid.CellValidating
        Dim newValue = e.FormattedValue.ToString.Trim   '<---trim added

'change value of cell without trims
        Dim aaa As DataGridViewCell = CType(sender, DataGridView).Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex)
        aaa.Value = newValue


        If Not Grid.Rows(e.RowIndex).IsNewRow Then              'And Not e.RowIndex = Grid.NewRowIndex - 1 Then
            Select Case e.ColumnIndex
                Case 1   'Name
                    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(newValue) Then

                        e.Cancel = True
                        Exit Select
                    End If           
                Case Else
            End Select
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: `but it completely doesn't work` - in which doesn´t it work? What cocnlusions did you get while debugging your code step by step? What value has  `e.FormattedValue.ToString` before and after Trim?

Comment: @Alex B. before it gave correct value and after trim it doing it right - trimming. This is correct. Now i do not know how to save that value aftertrimming to cell.

Comment: Like @jmcilhinney wrote put the code of the trim into `CellValidated` event handler and leave the is IsNullOrEmpty check in the `CellValidating` event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the wrong event.  `CellValidating` is for determining whether the contents of the cell is valid or not.  `CellValidated` or `CellLeave` would be more suited to your situation.

Comment: You do exactly what you would expect, but you do it in the handler for the correct event.

Comment: to be honest don't get it. What should i change in this event to make it works?

Answer (score 1):

In the CellValidating event this works for me.

```
//remove the event
grdDetails.CellValidating -= grdDetails_CellValidating;
//update current cell
grdDetails.CurrentCell.Value = "My New Value";
//force grid to commit update
grdDetails.EndEdit();
//rehook the event
grdDetails.CellValidating += grdDetails_CellValidating;
```

Comment: You have to set grdDetails.CurrentCell.Value = "My New Value" _after_ the EndEdit.